# Adding new column to pandas df based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following dataset:

```
ID   Asset   Boolean
1     "A"    True  
1     "B"    False  
1     "B"    False   
2     "A"    True
3     "A"    True
3     "A"    True
3     "B"    False
3     "B"    False
4     "A"    True
4     "A"    True
5     "A"    True
5     "B"    False
```

I want to add another column, which should evaluate to True only if all values in the column `Boolean` evaluate to True for the same `ID`. 
So something like this:

```
ID   Asset   Boolean  Check
1     "A"    True     False
1     "B"    False    False
1     "B"    False    False
2     "A"    True     True
3     "A"    True     False
3     "A"    True     False
3     "B"    False    False
3     "B"    False    False
4     "A"    True     True
4     "A"    True     True
5     "A"    True     False
5     "B"    False    False
```

I want to keep the original dataset for filter options. 
I could not figure out, how to iterate through the `Boolean` column taking the ID column into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df['Check'] = df.groupby('ID').Boolean.transform('all')

print(df)

    ID Asset  Boolean  Check
0    1     A     True  False
1    1     B    False  False
2    1     B    False  False
3    2     A     True   True
4    3     A     True  False
5    3     A     True  False
6    3     B    False  False
7    3     B    False  False
8    4     A     True   True
9    4     A     True   True
10   5     A     True  False
11   5     B    False  False
```