# What is the best way to add a new column to an existing pandas df based on external function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

cd = ['DE','AU','US','FR','GB','KR','IQ']
df = pd.DataFrame({'country_cd': cd})

def get_continent(country_cd):
    return 'some value'

%timeit df['continent1'] = df['country_cd'].apply(get_continent)
%timeit df['continent2'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_continent(x['country_cd']), axis =1)
%timeit df['continent3'] = df['country_cd'].map(get_continent)
```

`288 µs ± 3.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
780 µs ± 8.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
263 µs ± 4.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

From the above results, map seem to perform best for a single column. Is there a better way to achieve better results?
Also is there any gotcha that i am missing?

Please advise!

Comment: In general, in terms of efficiency: map and vectorized operations > apply > looping through rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394026/adding-new-column-to-pandas-df-based-on-condition?r=SearchResults&s=2|116.4602

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrong to not use a function?

```
%timeit df['continent4'] = ['some value']*len(df['country_cd'])
188 µs ± 8.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```